# Memoir class top margin varies throughout the document. It needs to be 1" exactly throughout

Tags: table-of-contents, margins, memoir

This is the pagestyle stuff shown for ToC only, others are similar:

```
\makepagestyle{toc}
  \makeevenfoot{toc}{}{\thepage}{}
  \makeoddfoot{toc}{}{\thepage}{}
\DoubleSpacing
  \makeevenhead{toc}{CHAPTER}{}{Page}
  \makeoddhead{toc}{CHAPTER}{}{Page}
```

This is I believe the main table creation code:

```
\let\oldtoc\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\clearpage\pagestyle{toc}\oldtoc}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand*{\tocheadstart}{\vspace*{-\topfiddle}}
\renewcommand*{\aftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{plain}%
  \par\nobreak \mbox{}\hfill{\normalfont Page}\par\nobreak}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{%
  \cftchapterfont\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
%\renewcommand*{\cftchaptername}{CHAPTER~}
%%% no extra space before the entry
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt plus 0pt}
%% no extra 'chapter' space in LoF/LoT
\renewcommand*{\insertchapterspace}{}
```

This is what is in my `.tex` file. Basic:

```
\newpage
\pagestyle{toc}
\tableofcontents*
\listoftables   % if you have any tables
\listoffigures  % if you have any figures
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{toc}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}
```

[image]

Comment: I included a image showing some examples. Not sure what happened to it. Basically, the title, abs and ack sections are ok. Goes bad at TOC and stays that way through out remainder. Have tried playing with the \pagestyle but not helping. THANKS.

Comment: I tried to salvage the question. However, it would be extremely helpful if you could reduce the 3 code segments you provided in your post into a single, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that includes your title, abstract (abs), a first chapter, and maybe the acknowledgements (ack).

Comment: Are you sure you don't exceed the declared height of the header somewhere? AFAIR, this might generate similar problems.

Comment: @mbork. A  working MWE is shown on a follow-up question I posted:" Problem with continuation of TOC in Memoir Class". If you check the package code, I believe the header height is specified there - but I am no expert by any means. I have learned quite a bit over the last week and and half. Still can't get the thing to work though...Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I threw in my comment only to mention one possible reason; I didn't have time to read you post carefully (not to mention to analyze the MWE).  Sorry for that, it is all I can do now...

Comment: @mbork. Thanks. I changed the header callout to 12pt and now at least it is double spacing between the 2nd toc page header and the continuation. The last problem remains: how to move the header/page down to 1" without messing up the 1st page TOC head which is now fine. Thanks for your help.