# Problem with continuation of TOC in Memoir Class

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, margins, memoir

This is basically continuation of earlier questions. I managed to fix (brute force) most issues. This one effects continuation pages of TOC, TOF, and chapters pages after the first. I assume it is the same issues throughout. As you can see, the continuation pages have the header single spaced from rest of the text PLUS it is not spaced correctly. As before, all text must start 1.0" from top of page. Thanks in advance for your help.[image: Image shows first and continuation pages of TOC. The TOC header is very close to 1" from page top and (unseen) subsections are double spaced below 'CHAPTER'. Below is continuation of TOC and 'CHAPTER' is not 1" spaced and subsections not double spaced. None of the fixes for other vertical spacing issues seems to effect this whatsoever. Thanks]

.tex code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{memoir}
\DoubleSpacing         % memoir's double spacing
\usepackage{mypkg}     % this package
\topmargin -0.4125in        % read Lamport p.163
\evensidemargin 0in     % same as oddsidemargin but for left-hand pages
\textheight 9.1in 
\parskip 7.2pt           % sets spacing between paragraphs
\parindent 0pt          % sets leading space for paragraphs
\DoubleSpacing
\begin{document}
\maxtocdepth{subparagraph} % put everything into the ToC
\pagestyle{toc}
\tableofcontents*
\mainmatter
\pagestyle{toc}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}
\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter{INTRODUCTION} 
\section{Background and Motivation}
\chapter{TWO} 
\section{Why ?}
\chapter{THREE} 
\section{Why not ?}
\subsection{Qualitat ave Qequirements}
\chapter{THREE} 
\section{Qualitat ave Qequirements}
\chapter{THREE} 
\section{Qualitat ave Qequirements}
\chapter{THREE} 
\section{Qualitat ave Qequirements}
\chapter{THREE} 
\section{Qualitat ave Qequirements}
\chapter{THREE} 
\section{Qualitat ave Qequirements}
\chapter{THREE} 
\section{Qualitat ave Qequirements}
\chapter{THREE} 
\section{Qualitat ave Qequirements}
\chapter{THREE} 
\section{Qualitat ave Qequirements}
\chapter{THREE} 
\section{Qualitat ave Qequirements}
\end{document}
```

My package file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypkg}
\@ifclassloaded{memoir}{\let\endpwasu\relax}{\let\endpwasu\endinput
  \PackageError{pwasu}{The pwasu package only works with the memoir class}{\@ehd}}
\endpwasu
% Some useful lengths for layout purposes
\newlength{\toptafiddle}
\newlength{\bottafiddle}
\newlength{\topfiddle}
\newlength{\botfiddle}
\newlength{\linespace}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.375in}{1.375in}{*}
%% bottom of text at 1in, footer below
%% top of header at 1in, first text line double spaced below base of header
\setlength{\linespace}{\baselineskip} %% the current equivalent of \onelineskip
\setlength{\headheight}{\lineskip}
\setlength{\headsep}{\linespace}
\addtolength{\headsep}{-\topskip}
\setlength{\uppermargin}{1in}
\makepagestyle{asu}
%% for continuation pages of the ToC, LoF, LoT, LoS
\makepagestyle{toc}
  \makeevenfoot{toc}{}{\thepage}{}
  \makeoddfoot{toc}{}{\thepage}{}
  \makeevenhead{toc}{CHAPTER}{}{Page}
  \makeoddhead{toc}{CHAPTER}{}{Page}
%% chapter style
\makechapterstyle{asu}{%
\setlength{\beforechapskip} {-.5\topfiddle}
\setlength{\afterchapskip} {\onelineskip}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{-0.2in}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{3pt}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\chapnamefont}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\centering\chapnumfont \thechapter}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\centering\vspace*{-\onelineskip}}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}

}
%%% (subsub)section styles
\setsecheadstyle{\centering\normalfont\vspace*{-\onelineskip}}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\centering\itshape\vspace*{-\onelineskip}}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\centering\vspace*{-\onelineskip}}
\setlength{\aftersecskip}{3pt}
%%%% Do the ToC
\let\oldtoc\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\clearpage\pagestyle{toc}\oldtoc}
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand*{\tocheadstart}{\vspace*{-.0225in}}
\renewcommand*{\aftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{plain}%
  \par\nobreak \mbox{}\hfill{\normalfont Page}\par\nobreak}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{%
  \cftchapterfont\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt plus 0pt}
\chapterstyle{asu}
\endinput
```

Comment: So is this question a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34437/memoir-class-top-margin-varies-throughout-the-document-it-needs-to-be-1-exactl, just with a more complete MWE?

Comment: It may not be clear from my problem statement and image, but text must start 1" below top of page and then (if header of any sort) the subsequent text must be double-spaced below the header. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can edit existing questions to include more information. If @Werner is right you should simply update your original question instead of posting a new one.

Comment: Werner, in addition to adding the MWE, I have managed to fix several sections (well, two actually - the TOC first page and the main text, first page only)  top margin issues. I am requesting help on the TOC second page specifically and hope that a similar solution will fix the rest of the top margin issues.

Comment: I see a small error. \ProvidesPackage{pwasu} should reference mypkg. Seems to work OK this way however.

Comment: You may (and maybe should) fix such mistakes at your own question just by editing it.

Comment: @Schweinebacke. I have since used the editing to fix this and some other minor mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: Obviously, the problem lies with the makeeven and makeodd head{toc}{Chapter}{}{page} statement that is required to add the header to secondary page of toc (and lof,lot) - all which have the same issue. Is there some command(s) I can directly add here that will 1) force the header to be spaced by 1" below page edge and 2) double space between the header and continuation of the toc (or lof,lot)? I have checked manual and extensive online search - I am out ideas. Any ideas at all appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: I am still working on this last problem. I have every other problem solved. I still need to get continuation pages to 1". My thesis is due now. Any ideas, suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks. Note that I have tried dozens of things. Read manual and have done countless web searches for ideas. Nothing seems to move the header on the continuation pages whatsoever. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm currently having the same problem - did you ever solve this?