# TOC and other Margin issues in Memoir Class

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

I am facing the same problem. I could add a space between Chapter-Page header and ToC text using the following approach: in `pwasu.sty` file:

```
\makepagestyle{toc}

\setlength{\headsep}{\linespace} %---Add this line to provide a gap between header & text.

\makeevenfoot{toc}{}{\thepage}{}

\makeoddfoot{toc}{}{\thepage}{}

\makeevenhead{toc}{CHAPTER}{}{Page}

\makeoddhead{toc}{CHAPTER}{}{Page}

\DoubleSpacing
```

Another related issue is that top-margin varies on each page. However bottom margin and side margins, once set remain the same. I used `\newgeometry` package to define textwidth and textheight.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34437/memoir-class-top-margin-varies-throughout-the-document-it-needs-to-be-1-exactl  and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34551/problem-with-continuation-of-toc-in-memoir-class?lq=1

Comment: Can you please complete your code snippet to a complete and minimal document allowing us to reproduce the problem?